# Is it possible to compress this expression to one line?

Tags: java, lambda, one-liner

i have this java function that searches for an object in an arraylist based on the name variable of the object

```
public Animal buscarAnimal(String animal){ 
        for(Animal a: animais){
            if(a.getNomeAnimal().equals(animal))return a;
        }
        return null;
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do all of the compararisons and the returning of the object all in one line, using foreach and lambdas, or maybe streams.
I tried for a some time, but i'm not really a pro and only got this far

```
animais.forEach((Animal a)->{if(a.getNomeAnimal().equals(animal)){return a;}});
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Stream` and `filter` then `findFist`. This returns an `Optional<Animal>`. If you don't want to change your method to return an `Optional<Animal>` (recommended), use `orElse(null)` to get your original behaviour.

```
return
    animais.stream().filter(a -> a.getNomeAnimal().equals(animal))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

In one line:

```
return animais.stream().filter(a -> a.getNomeAnimal().equals(animal)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Nice answer with a great explanation!